# Define default value to arguments in Snowflake Function (UDF)

Tags: arguments, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions, default-value

I want to create SQL function two params:

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myudf (varchar_argument VARCHAR, number_argument NUMBER) ...`

But I want to set default value if the user did not specify all arguments while calling
`select * from (table(myudf('varchar_argument'))`

I saw the option to create two functions with the same name but different arguments amount, but I dont want to duplicate my code since maintenance can be tricky.

any other option?

put default value in function creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a time of writing UDF default arguments are not supported.

Option 1: [Overloading functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/udf-stored-procedure-naming-conventions#overloading-procedures-and-functions)

Option 2: Passing second argument as NULL and handle it inside UDF

```
select * 
from (table(myudf('varchar_argument', NULL::NUMBER));
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myudf (varchar_argument VARCHAR, number_argument NUMBER) 
...
AS
SELECT *
FROM ...
WHERE col = varchar_argument
  AND col2 = COALESCE(number_argument , <default_value_here>);
```

---

**EDIT:**

Option 3: UDF's argument `DEFAULT value`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myudf (varchar_argument VARCHAR,
                                  number_argument NUMBER DEFAULT 10) 
...
AS
SELECT *
FROM ...
WHERE col = varchar_argument
  AND col2 = number_argument ;
```

Invocation:

```
select * 
from (table(myudf(varchar_argument => 'some_value'));
```